# How do I express html in popup on streamlit folium map?

Tags: html, popup, streamlit, folium

```
df_final['html_file']: html files are plotly graphs

   for i in range(0,len(df_final)):
    p = open(df_final['html_file'][i], 'rt', encoding='UTF8')
    popup = folium.Popup(components.html(p.read(), width=850, height=400, scrolling=True))
    
    folium.Circle([df_final['lats'].iloc[i],df_final['lngs'].iloc[i]],
                    radius=200,        
                    color='red',        
                    fill=True,
                    #fill_color='coral', 
                    fill_opacity=0.1, 
                    popup=popup
    ).add_to(map)
map.save("index.html")

st_folium(map, returned_objects=[], width = 1300, height = 1000)
```

HTML and map are displayed separately - I want to put HTML in the popup

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my answer here:
[Folium - add larger pop ups with data from XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486007/folium-add-larger-pop-ups-with-data-from-xml-file/71551416#71551416)

You can embed html code in an iFrame which is then put in your popup.